# Dynamic selection of node parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using Jenkins to run tests. I have many test suits (a string parameter) and many nodes. Particular test suits can be run only on specific nodes, for example:

- test_suite_1 can be run only on node_1, node_2 or node_3
- test_suite_2 can be run only on node_4 or node_5.

To run a test I have to select a test suite and a Node/Nodes, which is great and I still want to use this functionality.

What i want?
When I select only a test suite - and no Node will be selected by user - the Node will be selected dynamically by script/plugin - it should depend on selected test suite and depend of availability of node (for example I've selected test_suite_1 and node_1 is busy, then node_2 or node_3 should be selected by this script).

I know that NodeLabel parameter have a default Node - but as I mentioned before, particular test suits can be run only on specific nodes so it's not possible to set a default Node for every test suite.

How to automate selecting Node in NodeLabel parameter plugin?

I found Groovy Label Assignment plugin but when I have Node parameter and at the same time Label parameter - no matter what is in Label, value from Node parameter have higher priority.

Comment: Do you need to "choose" the specific node it runs on? If you added a label SUITE1 to node_1,2,3 and SUITE2 to node4,5, restrict jobs to run on nodes with specific label and and SUITE1 to test_suite_1, etc., then problem solved, isn't it? Jenkins will assign accordingly.

Comment: I want have possibility to:
1) select several nodes to run a test
2) no selecting node - then it should be selected dynamically
I can achieve each one separately:
1) Manually selected nodes:
- only Node parameter is needed and it works fine. I can select several nodes at once.
2) Dynamically selected nodes:
- Label parameter (NodeLabel parameter plugin)
- Groovy Label Assignment plugin
when I select a test suite, a Groovy Label Assignment plugin sets Label parameter to the appropriate value (Label can be a node name so I can specify in this script exact node if I want).

Comment: BUT I don't know how to merge theese two points into one, because when I use Node parameter and Label parameter in one job and for example will not select anything in Node parameter (master will be selected by default or another node if I will change default node) and groovy script will then select a Label based on selected test_suite and for example sets Label to node_1... But value in Label parameter have lower priority than value in Node and job will try to run on "master" node (or another default node).

Comment: When no default node will be selected in Node parameter configuration the same scenario causes that in build history there will be:
"pending—There are no nodes with the label ‘Job triggered without a valid online node‘"

Comment: Hi @maad-maad, I kniw it's been a while, but if the answer helped address your issue, consider marking as answered or at least up vote. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023570/how-to-run-a-job-on-first-available-node) was closed as a being too broad. My  reply to that was deleted as being not having sufficient context, so let's try answer this again...

(ps: you may wish to rephrase your question with the details you added in the comments make it more clear)

You have 2 tests and 5 nodes, broken into 2 groups.

Create a label (eg: GROUP_A) on nodes 1, 2, and 3:
Jenkins | Manage Nodes | [pick a Node] | Configure

 Under "Labels", add "**GROUP_A**", Save

Do similar (ie: GROUP_B) for nodes 4, 5

For test_suite_1, Configure, under General
[ **X** ] Restrict where this project can be run
Label Expression: "**GROUP_A**"

Do similar for test_suite_2.

Now, test_suite_1 will run on any of nodes in **GROUP_A** and test_suite_2 will only run on any nodes in **GROUP_B**. This is what [Node labels](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Nodelabelsforagents) are for. [Usage example here](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Using+Labels+for+Resource+Assignment+and+Job+Queuing+in+Jenkins).

Normally, Jenkins jobs are sticky, so they stick to the last node they ran on, unless it's down. You can change this behavior to run on the least busy node using the [Least Load Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload) ([wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Least+Load+Plugin)).

> From the description: *By default Jenkins tries to allocate a jobs to
>   the last node is was executed on. This can result in nodes being left
>   idle while other nodes are overloaded. This plugin overrides the
>   default behavior and assigns jobs to nodes with the least load.*

I don't know that you can have it default to group if no option is specified AND have it run on a specific node if you supply a parameter, but I also don't know you need to. You could investigate the use of "[Node and Label parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodelabelparameter)" plugin. Perhaps a regex of `(GROUP_A)||(${SELECTEDNODE})` where `SELECTEDNODE` is supplied from the choice option

We don't use the [Node and Label plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin), but I don't think you can have your job run simultaneously on all nodes ("1) select several nodes to run a test", "I can select several nodes at once"), unless you change to a multi-configuration project, despite the option to select multiple nodes; is it a "one of the selected" option? You'd have to test that.